# I couldn't help it

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does the sentence

> I was reluctant to go but I couldn't help it

I was confused by ***I couldn't help it***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"I can't help it" (and its variations) is an idiom which means "it's beyond my control." "It" can refer to the current situation, something that just happened, or in this case the action that the subject performed (going).
More literally, the sentence means that the subject didn't want to go, but something else was forcing him to go, or something bad would have happened had he not gone that he couldn't allow to happen.

Another example of the idiom in usage: a mother might say to her son, "Stop biting your fingernails." The child might reply "I can't help it," because his fingernail biting is already a habit and he does it without thinking.

Comment: What about the phrase __It couldn't be helped__? Does it have the same meaning?

Comment: Yes, and being a passive statement is useful if you want to say something was unavoidable, but it was not your fault (even if it was).

Comment: @D.B. Indeed it does, that is a very common variation of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "I couldn't help it" means that you were compelled to do something or you couldn't resist a temptation.

For example:

> I knew I shouldn't eat the cake, but I couldn't help it.

Meaning, you knew that it would wreck your diet, but you ate it anyway because you couldn't resist.